# How do I display all the results of update query in PHP and SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
<?php
include 'core/init.php';
include 'includes/overall/header.php';  

if(isset($_POST['btn_submit'])){

  $sqlQuery = mysql_query("UPDATE `position` SET `ATR`='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ATR'])."'");

  if(mysql_query($connection, $sqlQuery)){
        header('Location:page2.php');
    }
    else{
        echo "Error" .mysql_error();
    }

    $result = "SELECT  * FROM position";
    $finalResult = mysql_query($result) or die(mysql_error());

}
?>

<h2><font color="blue">Table that shows edit history:</h2>
<table border="1" cellpadding="5px" cellspacing="0" width="60%">
     <tr>
     <th><strong>row1</strong></th>
     <th><strong>row2</strong></th>
     <th><strong>row3</strong></th>
     <th><strong>row4</strong></th>
     <th><strong>row5</strong></th>
     </tr>

     <?php 

   while($row5 = mysql_fetch_assoc($finalResult)) { 
         echo "<td>".$row5['row1']."</td>";
         echo "<td>".$row5['row2']."</td>";
         echo "<td>".$row5['row3']."</td>";
         echo "<td>".$row5['row4']."</td>";
         echo "<td>".$row5['row5']."</td>";

     ?>
```

This code currently just displays one row of update what I am trying to do is display all updates and when I refresh it goes away I am aiming to create a history of updates, sorry I am new too php thanks!.

Comment: Totally useless code `if(mysql_query($connection, $sqlQuery)){
        header('Location:page2.php');
    }`

Comment: what do you mean I use select it only displays one of the results I need all update results

Comment: **Stop** using the deprecated `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`with prepared statemtens

Comment: It shows errors when I do and I coded it with mysql the entire application will change later

Comment: You should not make a Redirect after `updating`

Comment: Ok you guys are "good at coding" why don't you solve this instead of criticising my code? or give me ideas why doesn't it display all the updates by the user? and why does it go away when refreshed?

Comment: Where is your while end? I didn't find while loop end. It should be an error.

Comment: sorry it was here:

Comment: <?php
    
     break;
  mysql_close();
  
  
  }
  
  mysql_free_result($sqlQuery);
  
  
   

   
?>

Comment: Update your question. Other wise difficult  to solve.